# Batch animation doesn't work at runtime

Tags: batch-file

when i run it does not pause after the fist frame please help

```
@echo off 
title line!
color 0a

echo.
echo -----------------------------------
echo press a key to Make The line spin    
echo -----------------------------------
echo.
echo Made By: alex.page
echo.

pause >nul


echo -----------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo        ---
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo ------------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo       \
echo        \
echo         \
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo ------------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo         | 
echo         |         
echo         |  
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo ------------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo           /
echo          /       
echo         /
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo ------------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo        ---
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo ------------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo       \
echo        \
echo         \
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo ------------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo         | 
echo         |         
echo         |  
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo ------------------
echo.                 
echo.
echo.
echo           /
echo          /       
echo         /
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.                  
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo ------------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo        ---
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo ------------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo        ---
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo ------------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo       \
echo        \
echo         \
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo ------------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo         | 
echo         |         
echo         |  
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo -----------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo           /
echo          /       
echo         /
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo -----------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo        ---
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo -----------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo       \
echo        \
echo         \
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo -----------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo         | 
echo         |         
echo         |  
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo ------------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo           /
echo          /       
echo         /
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo -----------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo        ---
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo ------------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo        ---
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo ------------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo       \
echo        \
echo         \
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo -----------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo         | 
echo         |         
echo         |  
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo -----------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo           /
echo          /       
echo         /
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo -----------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo        ---
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo -----------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo       \
echo        \
echo         \
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo -----------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo         | 
echo         |         
echo         |  
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo -----------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo           /
echo          /       
echo         /
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

echo -----------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo        ---
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls

pause
```

Answer (score 3):

The `|` character is special to the command interpreter and must be escaped with a `^`. You want to use this instead:

```
 echo         ^|
```

Comment: I'd say this would be a great candidate as well for having each frame of your animation be a named label.  Then when you ping for delay, you just  can simply goto each frame.  It'll save you from having to make it crazy long.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was talking about regarding the animation labels.  For simplicity I used two frames, but the proof of concept is what's important.

```
@echo off 
title Spin
color 0a

echo.
echo -----------------------------------
echo Press a key to make the line spin!    
echo -----------------------------------
echo.
echo.
pause >nul
cls

:Animate
Call :Frame1
Call :Frame2
Call :Frame1
Call :Frame2
echo Spin complete!
pause>nul
exit

:Frame1
echo -----------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo        ---
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
GOTO:EOF

:Frame2
echo -----------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo         ^|
echo         ^|
echo         ^|
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo ------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
GOTO:EOF
```